# C++ Is it possible to leak memory if i'm not using dynamic memory

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, stack-memory

None of my code uses dynamic memory, but I do have a vector of pointers to a struct called `Node`, and in my code, I do lose references to those `Node`s at one point. The struct looks like this:

```
struct Node {
int value;
Node* next;
};
```

I also have a for loop that tries to find the smallest value in my vector of Node pointers by taking the smallest `Node` off as I go. Here, lists is the vector of `Node` pointers, and add is the previous smallest value.

```
for (int i = 1; i < int(lists.size()); ++i) {
        if (lists[i]->value <= add) {
            add = lists[i]->value;
            lists[i] = lists[i]->next;
            break;
        }
    }
```

I thought I couldn't leak memory if I was just in the stack though...

Comment: Indeed you can't leak memory that isn't dynamically allocated. What makes you think you are leaking memory? The code you posted does not reflect that.

Comment: Where are you getting your `Node*` to store in the list?  Are you taking a reference of a `Node` at some point or do you actually call `new` somewhere in your program?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "dynamic memory" means. For example, if you use `std::vector`, you are using dynamic memory. If you have pointers, you are almost certainly using dynamic memory.

Comment: @user3427419: "If you have pointers, you are almost certainly using dynamic memory" - unless those pointers are pointing at objects allocated on the stack.

Comment: I was originally having pointers to objects on the stack, but I realize the node needs to be dynamically allocated instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Node` referenced in the `lists` array is dynamically allocated, you should free all of them manually. Otherwise there will be memory leak. You can find more details on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak